# Show that $\log(x) < \sqrt[4]{x}$ for all $x > x_0$.

Tags: inequality

From a plot I know that
$$
\log(x) < \sqrt[4]{x} \text{ for } x > 5504.
$$

Is there an easy way to show it?
I could only do it with the analytic toolbox: Derivation and co.
But if there is an easier way, I would prefer it instead.

Comment: Show that $4\log w < w$ for sufficiently large $w$.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, it should be $5503$

Comment: @Gary I see the point. How can I do that?

Comment: $w^4 < \frac{w^5}{5! }<\mathrm{e}^w$ for $w>5! =120$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
 \log(u) = 1 + \log\left( \frac ue\right) \le 1 + \left( \frac ue -1 \right) = \frac ue
$$
holds for all $u > 0$. It follows that
$$
 \log(x) = 8 \log(x^{1/8}) \le \frac 8e x^{1/8}
$$
and that is $< x^{1/4}$ for
$$
 x > \left( \frac 8e \right)^8 \approx 5628.13 \, .
$$
(Numerical calculations show that $\log(x) < x^{1/4}$ holds for $ x> x_0 \approx 5503.66$.)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want some value of $x_0$ rather than the best possible, you could rather crudely argue as follows: $\exp(\sqrt[4]{x})\geq \frac{x^2}{8!}$ since the RHS is a term of the expansion, and so $\exp(\sqrt[4]{x})\geq x$ for $x\geq 8!$, then take logs.

You can do a bit better by taking the twelfth term instead, getting $\lceil\sqrt{12!}\rceil=21887$ instead of $8!=40320$; this is the optimal term to look at if you're just going to bound by a single term.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle ~f(x) = \log(x), ~g(x) = \sqrt[4]{x}.$

Then:

- $~f(5504) < g(5504).~$
- $f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}.$
- $\displaystyle g'(x) = \frac{1}{4x^{3/4}}.$

Notice that

$$x > 256 \implies x^{1/4} > 4 \implies x > 4x^{3/4} \implies $$

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{4x^{3/4}} = g'(x).$$

So,

- $f(5504) < g(5504).$
- $\forall ~x \geq 5504, ~f'(x) < g'(x).$

This is conclusive.